# Is there a way to add Google Docs-like comments to any web page?

Tags: web-development, google-workspace, comments

You know the comments on Google Docs word processing documents?  And how it creates a little discussion over in the right-hand margin?

I love it.  Great for collaboration.  I want to free it from Google Docs so I can use it with clients to discuss mock-ups or scaffolded websites.

Searching Google for "add comments [or discussions] to any website" only gets you results for adding blog-like comments (Disqus, JS-Kit, etc.)

Anyone know of a solution for what I'm after here?

Comment: Is a web annotation service what you're looking for? If so, there are [quite a few](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/top-web-annotation-and-markup-tools/) available.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a chat room or shoutbox.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice one I've seen used, [here](http://hot-things.net/). It's an AJAX chatroom/shoutbox with PHP, so you can add it in or delete it at will. There is also a lot of customization involved.

Comment: I don't think that's the right link. You've linked to a TED talk on "massive scale online collaboration".

Comment: That's embarrasing lol. Unfortunately, I'm not in a place where I can test the link for a while, but I'm certain that's the one to use. Good catch!

Comment: Just tested it. That's the right one. =P

Comment: Thanks! @Sean, do you need more information? If not, then please mark this answer as the correct one.